# Android In-App Billing: set targeted countries prices

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am currently trying to set different prices based on country for a in-app product. Based on Google's tutorial:

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html

On image 4 there is a UI portion that says "target countries are inherited from the owning application. Click here to change targeted countries!"

Well I can't see this part on my interface! I looked into Edit Application page and there is no place called "targeted countries". I found the countries list, but changing it does not affect the in-app product page.

Does anyone know how to get this in-app product different prices option?

Thanks!

Comment: 1.99USD, but I want to use different values for different countries.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that setting in-app billing different prices is only available in some countries:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1169947

Comment: 2021 Is this still the same?